# How to control the specific size of plot in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, julia

Let us suppose that I am plotting a few plots with pyplot/matplotlib. Now, the first has to have tick marks and tick labels, and only the first. The last has to have a colorbar and some marks for scale. If I do a script specifying  the figure size, the plot proper in the last and first plots is drawn with smaller sizes, as the figure has to make room for the extra markings. And I seem to be not able to control that, in an automatic way, like making the other plots at the same scale inside a larger figure or something like that. 
Example code (it looks a little non-pythonic because I am using PyPlot inside Julia):

```
using PyPlot

SomeData=randn(64,64,3)

for t=1:3

 figure(figsize=(3.0,3.0))    
 imagen=imshow(SomeData[:,:,t], origin="lower")

if t!=3

    xticks([]) 
    yticks([]) 

    else
        tick_params(labelsize=8, direction="out")
    end

if t==1

    cbx=colorbar(imagen, fraction=0.045, ticks=[]) 
    cbx[:set_label]("Some proper English Label", fontsize=8)

end

   savefig("CSD-$t.svg",dpi=92)

end
```

Thanks in advance-

Comment: The code that you listed here is quite long, complex (and in Spanish, which probably creates a barrier to at least some users of this site).  Furthermore, it references objects, like `tiemposinteresantes` that are never defined in the code.  You may get better luck finding an answer if you (a) greatly simplify your code to focus on the essence of what you are trying to accomplish and (b) make it reproducible.  View this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for info on creating such a minimal working example.

Comment: Done, I simplified the example but it is still long as it has to show the conflicting cases.

Comment: Looks better.  I'm about to travel for a week but will take a look if it is unanswered when I return.  With any luck, the revisions will get it back to the top of people's notice and it will attract an answer sooner.

Comment: We need a minimal working example, that includes all of the using commands for the packages you use, and sample data. In that way we can run the code and iterate on it.

Comment: Hello @DavidP.Sanders, how's your Sabbath? Done, did the `using PyPlot` and added line to generate sample data.